# Is anything faster than .Any() to check that condition?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have been searching for a way to do the following with a faster EF query :

```
 using (DAL.MandatsDatas db = new DAL.MandatsDatas())
 {
   if(db.ARTICLE.Any( t => t.condition == condition))
      oneArticle = db.ARTICLE.First( t => t.condition == condition);
 }
```

It works fine, but the more i add of these, the slower it feels.
It just looks like it goes through all the rows 2 times (i don't know if it's the case)

I've been searching, saw people using the `count() > 0` and other irrelevant stuff...

1. Is there a faster way to check if someting exist and then take it.
2. Also i was wondering if the `FirstOrDefault()` could help my case, how does it work ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `FirstOrDefault` is better here:

```
oneArticle = db.ARTICLE.FirstOrDefault(t => t.condition == condition);
```

Basically `Any` will do one select, and then `First` will do one more. While `FirstOrDefault` will do the same `First` does, and just return `null` if there was no output, thus eliminating the need to run another selection operation.

Comment: Ok, so "default" is a nice little word for " it's just going to be null if there isin't anything " ? Well that's that, many thanks.

Comment: @AntoinePelletier, almost that. Precisely it sounds like "it is going to be default(T) if there isn't anything", so you will have null for reference types and default values for value types such as 0 for integer

Comment: Default is `default(T)` where T is the "thing" you are getting the first or default of. For classes, default is `null` for structs (like `int`, `double`, or `DateTime`) it reruns the value of `new T()`, usually 0 or some representation close to that

Comment: @Andrei bah, if I was not typing on my phone I would have been faster than you to respond both times :)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain haha ! An answer contest ? funnyest thing i ever saw on SO

Comment: @AntoinePelletier, then you may fancy reading [this thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, FirstOrDefault will be faster because it will only query once. The way it works is if no rows where available it will return `null`, if there was rows available it returns the fist row based on any ordering you applied (if any).